# Issue with variable initialization when non-static

Tags: java, arrays, initialization, javac

I'm trying to double an array in a non-static context in the following way:

```
public class Test {
    int[] data=new int[1];

    public void Double(){
        if(data == null){
            int[] data=new int[1];
        }
        int[] data=new int[data.length*2];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Test table = new Test();
        table.data=new int[1];
    }
}
```

The javac won't compile it because it warns me that

> variable data might not have been initialized

Even though it obviously has been initialized, how can I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring a local `data` variable in your `Double()` method (actually you are declaring two such variables), which hides the instance variable having the same name.

Therefore, in the statement :

```
int[] data=new int[data.length*2];
```

You are accessing `data.length` before the local `data` variable is initialized.

Change it to :

```
public void Double(){
    if(data == null){
        data=new int[1];
    } else {
        data=new int[data.length*2];
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry was reading too superficially, and trying to find the fly in the soup.

Comment: @Eran It should have been called `Test`. `double` is a keyword, and therefore not an identifier, and therefore not a legal method name.

Comment: @EJP I didn't think about it. However, since the purpose of this method is to double the length of the member array, perhaps `doubleArray()` would have fit better. Calling it with the same name as the class would have been confusing too, since it's not a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely pointless. `data` cannot possibly be null at the point you are testing it, and the following line where you are declaring and intializing a local variable that falls out of scope immediately is equally pointless, so all the related code can be just deleted.